# how to backup and minify the backup (Windows 10 for ARM)?

Tags: windows

how to backup and minify Raspberry Pi with installed Windows 10?

I want to deploy my modified rpi4 windows10 installation to multiple SD cards with different amount of storage while saving storage on my disk with the minified backup-file and making deployment faster.

Backup/restore to the same SD card is working when I use Win32DiskImager. But I'm currently not able to place it on another card as they are to small. Using Linux images this is very easy using PiShrink.

Comment: Execute `cleanmgr` and delete all volume shadow copies. You can also execute TRIM command via PowerShell ` Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter H -ReTrim -Verbose`.